# Feign can not connect to localhost

Tags: java, spring-cloud-feign, feign

When using `spring-cloud-feign` to connect to localhost Feign can not find the url and instead gives me the following error message.

```
    2019-11-13 12:01:55.553 ERROR 23798 --- [nio-4060-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is feign.RetryableException: Connection refused (Connection refused) executing POST http://localhost:4061/test] with root cause

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1226) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:990) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1340) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1315) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at feign.Client$Default.convertAndSend(Client.java:174) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
    at feign.Client$Default.execute(Client.java:77) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:110) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:80) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.login(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.test.service.PhpSendService.login(PhpSendService.kt:13) ~[main/:na]
    at com.test.delegate.SessionApiDelegateImpl.login(SessionApiDelegateImpl.kt:15) ~[main/:na]
    at com.test.api.SessionApi.login(SessionApi.java:40) ~[main/:na]
    at com.proj.bff.api.SessionApi$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cb0ac622.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:120) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.proj.bff.api.SessionApiController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ff5ae108.login(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_232]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_232]
```

My Feign Client:

```
@FeignClient(name = "php", url = "http://localhost:4061/test")
interface PhpClient {
    @RequestMapping(method = [RequestMethod.POST])
    fun login(postData: LoginAction): PhpResponse
}
```

When I change the url to `google.com` for example I can see that the request properly gets sent and google gives me a response.

How can I properly access localhost when using Feign?

I can reach the endpoint with Postman so that is not the problem. The problem seems to specifically be in the fact that Feign cannot target localhost?

Edit: Switching to OkHttp like so

```
Request.Builder()
            .url("http://localhost:4061/test")
            .build()
```

works. Why doesn't it work with feign?

Comment: What happens when you: ping http://localhost:4061/test or curl -X POST http://localhost:4061/test ?

Comment: @JohnnyAlpha curl works, ping doesn't

Comment: @JohnnyAlpha Actually pinging "localhost" works. Pinging "localhost:4061" does not.

Comment: Oh I see. What does the ping do? Does it just hang? By the way, how about curl -X POST localhost:4061/test ?

Comment: I don't think you can ping a port. curl -X works. I believe it is an error with how I give the URL to feign

Comment: Ah ok, I was wondering if a 404 was being sent back, or perhaps the endpoint not being up at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the mistake was not in feign but that I tried to connect to a phpstorm built-in server.

So for me the fix was changing my configuration in phpstorm from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`. Apparently when using `localhost` phpstorm prefers IPv6 somehow.